# StackoverFlow error on trait creating self object

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to define an User object which extends a trait. Trait contains a collection of user object. When I try to create a new user. I get Stackoverflow error, I am not able to understand why

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class User(email:String) extends userTrait


trait userTrait {
  self:User =>
  val administrators = new User("test@ab.com")::new User("test2@ab.com")::Nil
  def isAdminstrator = administrators.contains(this)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class User
defined trait userTrait

scala> new User("test")
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  ... 1024 elided
```

Comment: When creating the User with new User, this initalises administrators in the trait. Which calls new User, which initialises administators in the trait. Which calls new User..... bang, stack overflow. It's not all obvious what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I get the point. I want the trait to contain a collection of super users. How do I initialize that collection ?

Comment: I don't like putting data into traits. I still treat them a little bit like Java's interfaces with defined methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cyclic condition here. `User extends userTrait` (which intern initializes `new User ...`)

Answer (score 3):

"How do I initialize that collection ?"
You can simply prepend `val administrators` with `lazy`

```
trait userTrait {
  self: User =>
  /* >>> */ lazy val administrators = 
    new User("test@ab.com") :: new User("test2@ab.com") :: Nil
  def isAdminstrator = administrators.contains(this)
}
case class User(email: String) extends userTrait

println(new User("test").isAdminstrator)
// prints false
println(new User("test@ab.com").isAdminstrator)
// prints true
```